# Disable logical structure display in Variables View

Tags: java, eclipse

How to disable the special treatment of logical structures in eclipse's [Variables View](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fvariables%2Fref-variables_view.htm)?

### Summary

Classes implementing `java.util.Collection` or `java.util.Map` are rendered by calling the respective 
`[entrySet().]toArray()` methods and shown in a tree-ish structure.

The corresponding preference page is `Java -> Debug -> Logical Structures`, where the definitions for `java.util.Collection` and `java.util.Map` are predefined and cannot be altered or disabled.

### My particular situation

Whenever the code enters my collection class in debug mode it immediately tries to call `toArray()` in the background (1) (probably due to the `this` node being present in the [Variables View](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fvariables%2Fref-variables_view.htm)). However, at some points, the class is just not ready for it and crashes.

I'm fully aware that methods like `toArray()` should be free of side-effects and in the project I'm currently working on I can safely leave them empty for the stage of development (or modify them so they don't hurt me), but I'd like to deal with this the 'eclipse way'.
Thus it would be much worse (basically unavoidable), if for example the code of `toArray()` itself needed to be debugged.

### Notes

(1) confirmation code

```
@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    new Exception("toArray was called").printStackTrace(System.out);
    return super.toArray();
}
```

However, the resulting stack-trace is completely broken; I don't call that `toArray()` at line 45 in `Testing` (I don't even have such an object reference), but it was the line I debugged when eclipse's `toArray()` kicked in.

```
java.lang.Exception: toArray was called
    at prv.izruo.<project>.util.SAXParser$CursorObject$1.toArray(SAXParser.java:511)
    at prv.izruo.<project>.test.Testing.read(Testing.java:45)
    at prv.izruo.<project>.test.Testing.main(Testing.java:36)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'eclipse way' in this case is not disabling an existing feature, but overriding it with another, more precise feature.

In particular this means adding another definition in the already mentioned preference page, that refers to a type more precise than `java.util.Collection`, let's say `SAXParser.CursorObject` (just ignoring the anonymous inner type for the sake of this example - actually its superclass must be used).

This will cut off unwanted calls to `toArray()` for all instances of `SAXParser.CursorObject`, but preserve the same behavior for all other instances of `java.util.Collection`.

So, in a nutshell:

1. Go to `Java -> Debug -> Logical Structures`.
2. Hit `Add...`.
3. Select the class to 'disable' the behavior for.
4. Add a description (because eclipse will force you to do so).
5. Insert code that doesn't hurt you.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable logical structures in the view (e.g. the variables view) using the  [image: Show logical structures button] "Show logical structures" button.

[image]

The button [image: Show logical structures button] is [available in](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-showlogical.htm):

- [Variables View](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-showlogical.htm)
- [Expressions View](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-showlogical.htm)
- Registers View

---

**Enabled**

[image]

**Disabled**

[image]